# How to determine if an integer is even or odd

Tags: python

```
def is_odd(num):
    # Return True or False, depending on if the input number is odd. 
    # Odd numbers are 1, 3, 5, 7, and so on. 
    # Even numbers are 0, 2, 4, 6, and so on.
```

I'm wondering what you would do from here to get those answers.

Comment: I'm wondering what you have tried so far

Comment: You should really tell us what you've tried up until now.  Even if what you tried hasn't worked it is better than nothing.  Playing around with the language is what is going to make you better, not asking the internet.

Comment: Clue: How do you do it without a computer?

Comment: Question closed because "not clear" ... "cannot be answered"! Actually closed because no effort was done by the OP (this reason should be in the list once for all, as it is a valid one, it would be clear instead of being ridiculous). Then 12 views per day since it was closed. So maybe the answer provided before it was closed is actually useful and such questions have their place here. For me the reason to search was to understand if some built-in function existed (`is_integer()` function exists, why not `is_odd()`?)

Answer (score 30):

```
def is_odd(num):
    return num & 0x1
```

It is not the most readable, but it is quick:

```
In [11]: %timeit is_odd(123443112344312)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 164 ns per loop
```

versus

```
def is_odd2(num):
   return num % 2 != 0

In [10]: %timeit is_odd2(123443112344312)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 267 ns per loop
```

Or, to make the return values the same as `is_odd`:

```
def is_odd3(num):
   return num % 2

In [21]: %timeit is_odd3(123443112344312)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 205 ns per loop
```

Comment: Isn't it going to return 1 or 0?

Comment: @Elalfer -- That's just a minor issue.  You can pretty much always use `1` in place of `True`.

Comment: Is there any reason to choose `0x1` rather than simply `1`?

Comment: @mgilson: It looks funnier.

Comment: @mgilson: No difference :)

Comment: 1 should be fine as well. But `0x1` looks more clear. I believe `%` timing is higher due to `!= 0` comparison, which actually returns `True` or `False` instead of `1` or `0`

Comment: @TimPietzcker -- Yeah, that's what I was guessing as well ... I don't usually use binary operations so I wasn't sure if it was more conventional to always use hex when doing binary ops ...

Comment: @mgilson: Seems best to leave the hex prefix off when the number's the same in hexadecimal and decimal.

Comment: I prefer it with the prefix, as that conveys the feel that the operation is bit-by-bit. Especially true in a more complex situation, such as testing flag bits, where SOME of the values wouldn't be the same in hex and decimal, but others would be.  E.g `if num & 0x10:` .. `elif num & 0x01:`.

Answer (score 8):

```
def is_odd(num):
   return num % 2 != 0
```

Symbol "%" is called modulo and returns the remainder of division of one number by another.

Comment: `return bool(num % 2)` or `return bool(num & 1)`