# Python function, odd, that takes in one number and returns True

Tags: python

Here is condition.

Write a Python function, odd, that takes in one number and returns True when the number is odd and False otherwise.

Condition is x: int or float.

and returns: True if x is odd, Falae otherwise

My code is

```
def odd(x):
  while x % 2 != 0:

    return (x % 2 == 1)
```

When if odd(62) above code is works, but odd(62) output is None. How can I correct False answer?

Please Help me.

Answer (score 4):

Your function doesn't return anything if the number is not odd. You don't need a while loop at all:

```
>>> def odd(x):
...     return x % 2 != 0
... 
>>> odd(62)
False
>>> odd(63)
True
```

Also see other ways to check if the number is odd or not:

- [How to determine if an integer is even or odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651025/how-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a `while` loop, a simple `if` will do it. The reason you get none is because the `while` loop doesn't run in the "even" condition so there is no return.

An even simpler way of writing it is to return the condition itself:

```
def odd(x):
    return x % 2 == 1
```

Comment: Sorry.. condition is should use the % (mod) operator, not if.

Comment: @user3404122 I meant that an if statement would be valid but not a while (`if x%2==1: return True else: return False`). You'll see in my example that I recommend returning the modulus of the input.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is messing it up.

```
def odd(x):
  return x % 2 == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`return (x % 2 != 0)`

This will return a boolean value; evaluates True if number is odd and False otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

def odd(x):
    '''
    x: int
    returns: True if x is odd, False otherwise
    '''
    while x%2 != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False