# Create a matrix of alternating zeroes and random numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to write some code that will create a matrix of alternating 1/-1 and 0 i.e:

```
[-1  0 -1  0  1  0  1  0 -1  0]
[ 0  1  0 -1  0  1  0 -1  0  1]
[ 1  0  1  0 -1  0 -1  0 -1  0]
[ 0  1  0 -1  0 -1  0 -1  0  1]
[ 1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0]
```

I've created a class that generates a matrix of zeroes and appends it with 1 or -1 and I have tried messing with my for loop and slicing my matrix but I can't seem to generate the matrix I'd like above. I have an intermediate level of python knowledge so I appreciate that a solution to my problem using the code I've created might not be particularly elegant but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


#constants
N = 10 #dimensions of matrix


class initial_lattice: 
    def __init__(self,N):   #create initial matrix of size NxN
        self.N=N
        self.matrix_lattice()

    def matrix_lattice(self):
        self.lattice = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=int) #creates initial matrix of zeroes
        for x in range(0,N):    
            for y in range(0,N):
                self.lattice[x,y]=random.choice([1,-1]) #randomly chooses values of 1 and -1 and appends matrix

lattice1=initial_lattice(N) 


print lattice1.lattice
```

Comment: I have very little experience in Python in particular but this seems a rather simple problem, can you not simply implement the following pseudocode: https://hastebin.com/gijotabaso.pas

Answer (score 7):

the even/odd rows idea seems fine, a variation:

```
def matrix_lattice(self):
    self.lattice = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (N, N))
    self.lattice[::2, ::2] = 0
    self.lattice[1::2, 1::2] = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

There may be a better solution, but this one definitely works:

```
def matrix_lattice(m,n):
  mask = np.ones((m,n), dtype=int) # All 1s
  mask[1::2, ::2] = 0 # Clean even fields in odd rows
  mask[::2, 1::2] = 0 # Clean odd fields in even rows
  u = np.random.randint(2, size=(m,n)) * 2 - 1 # 1s and -1s      
  return u * mask # Superimpose the matrices

print(matrix_lattice(5,5))
#array([[-1,  0,  1,  0,  1],
#       [ 0, -1,  0,  1,  0],
#       [ 1,  0,  1,  0, -1],
#       [ 0,  1,  0, -1,  0],
#       [ 1,  0, -1,  0, -1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer making a filter based on the `mod` of the indices, multiplied by a random +-1 matrix.  E.g:

```
def my_matrix(N=10, toggle=0):

    m       = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (N, N))
    [j,k]   = np.indices([N,N])
    filter  = (j + k + toggle)%2

    return filter*m
```

Answer (score 0):

Intead of filling with random and zeroing, I'd fill with zeros and input the random values

```
def matrix_lattice(self):
    self.lattice = np.zeros((N, N))
    self.lattice[::2,   ::2] = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (-(-N // 2), -(-N // 2)))
    self.lattice[1::2, 1::2] = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (N // 2,     N // 2)))
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np 
import random

class SpecialMat:
    def __init__(self, m, n):
        self.dim = (m, n)  # matrix dimension
        self.members = (-1, 1)
        self.data = self.__matrix_lattice(self)

    def display(self):
        print(self.data)

    @staticmethod
    def __matrix_lattice(self):
        m = self.dim[0]
        n = self.dim[1]
        L = self.members
        a = np.zeros((m, n), dtype=int)
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                if self._is_odd(j + i):
                    a[i, j] = random.choice(L)
        return a

    def _is_odd(self, num):
        return num % 2 is not 0
```

then in Python (3.6):

```
from <yourPythonFileName> import SpecialMat
M = SpecialMat(10, 5)  # should work with any integers
M.display()
[[ 0  1  0  1  0  1  0 -1  0 -1]
 [-1  0  1  0 -1  0  1  0  1  0]
 [ 0 -1  0  1  0 -1  0 -1  0  1]
 [-1  0  1  0 -1  0  1  0  1  0]
 [ 0  1  0  1  0  1  0 -1  0 -1]]
```

`def _is_odd` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651025/how-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd)

Comment: You matrix has a different structure. The 0s and 1s are not alternating.

Comment: @DYZ, you're right, realized it but had to run an errand. just uploaded the corrected version ;)

Comment: also corrected it so it create a m-by-n matrix as shown by OP

Comment: Not to mention that you are turning a trivial operation of half a dozen lines into an overkilled class.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: because the OP wrote a class