# Sifting even number with for and append functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def sieve(numbers):
   odd = []
   for i in numbers:
      if (i//2) != 2:
         odd.append(i)
   return odd

a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 5]
print(sieve(a))

Output:
[2, 6, 8]
```

I want this function to sift even numbers out and as you can see my if statement is using floor division to divide the value of i to 2 and if it is not equivalent to 2 then it is an odd number. However, the output I get only retains the even numbers. Why is that?

Comment: Because dividing a number by 2 isn't how you check if it's odd... Your code checks if the number is equal to 4 (or 5).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if an integer is even or odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651025/how-to-determine-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd)

Comment: Try it with modulo: `if i%2 != 0:`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a confusion with `//` operator. The `//` is a floor division operator which is very similar to the division operator `/`. It returns the result of division without floating numbers. You can check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers):

```
>>> a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 5]
>>> for i in a:
        print i//2
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3
4
2
```

In order to find odd/even numbers you can use modulo operator `%` as @lgle said:

```
>>> for i in a:
        print i%2
```

**Output:**

```
0
0
0
0
1
```